# Magento 2.1: create a WYSIWYG field in a custom widget

Tags: magento-2.1, widgets, wysiwyg

Is there a way to create a custom widget with WYSIWYG fields? I followed this tutorial [here](http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-2-add-types-wysiwyg-editor-text-area-custom-widget/#comment-4478) but when I enter data, they are not saved.

Answer (score 6):

You follow the [this url](https://www.toptal.com/magento/custom-widgets-in-magento-2) for creating custom widgets. Now as per your requirement for WYSIWYG editor.

Open widget.xml file and add new parameter, the code is below.

**etc/widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget class="Toptal\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\Samplewidget" id="toptal_customwidget_samplewidget">
        <label>Toptal Sample Widget</label>
        <description></description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="widgettitle" sort_order="10" visible="true" xsi:type="text">
                <label>Title</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="widgetcontent" sort_order="20" visible="true" xsi:type="textarea">
                <label>Content</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="contentnew" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="20" >
                <label>Custom Content</label>
                <block class="Toptal\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\Editor" />
            </parameter>
        </parameters>       
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Also, create Editor.php class file

**Block/Widget/Editor.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 www.magebuzz.com
 */

namespace Toptal\CustomWidget\Block\Widget;

Class Editor extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $wysiwygConfig;
    protected $factoryElement;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $factoryElement,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        $data = []
    ) {
        $this->factoryElement = $factoryElement;
        $this->wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $editor = $this->factoryElement->create('editor', ['data' => $element->getData()])
            ->setLabel('')
            ->setForm($element->getForm())
            ->setWysiwyg(true)
            ->setConfig(
                $this->wysiwygConfig->getConfig([
                    'add_variables' => false,
                    'add_widgets' => false,
                    'add_images' => false
                ])
            );

        if ($element->getRequired()) {
            $editor->addClass('required-entry');
        }
        $element->setData('after_element_html', $editor->getElementHtml());
        $element->setValue(''); // Hides the additional label that gets added.
        return $element;
    }
}
```

Lastly flush cache

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Hello @kishor, I have successfully added TinyMCE editor, but when I add <a> and then try to save my widget, I am getting an error as:
*Failed to execute 'setStartBefore' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.*

Comment: here the source of the solution. https://github.com/dmatthew/magento2-widget-parameters But the Error reported by @chirag still exists

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution: the widget had to be inserted via the "Widgets section" of the Admin and not by the "Pages" one. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2.4 the above answers gave me a bug where I first had to click "show / hide editor". I fixed this by implementing it with a textarea and parse it afterwards with JS. I got inspired by core module: `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Helper\Form\Wysiwyg;`

```
    class Editor extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

    const TEXT_AREA_ID = 'stepsContentWidget';

    protected $_elementFactory;

    /**
     * @var SecureHtmlRenderer
     */
    protected $secureRenderer;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory,
        ?SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer = null,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->secureRenderer = $secureRenderer ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SecureHtmlRenderer::class);
        $this->_elementFactory = $elementFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare chooser element HTML
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element Form Element
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
     */
    public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $input = $this->_elementFactory->create("textarea", ['data' => $element->getData()]);
        $input->setId(self::TEXT_AREA_ID);
        $input->setForm($element->getForm());
        $input->setClass("widget-option input-textarea admin__control-text");
        if ($element->getRequired()) {
            $input->addClass('required-entry');
        }

        $element->setData('after_element_html', $input->getElementHtml() . $this->addAfterHtmlJs() . $this->getAfterElementHtmlCss());
        return $element;
    }

    public function addAfterHtmlJs()
    {
        $scriptString = <<<HTML
            require([
                'jquery',
                'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
            ], function(jQuery){
                wysiwygcompany_description = new wysiwygSetup('{$this->getHtmlId()}', {
                        "width":"100%%",  // defined width of editor
                        "height":"200px", // height of editor
                        "plugins":[], // for image
                        "tinymce4":{"toolbar":"formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap","plugins":"advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table",
                     }
                 });
                 wysiwygcompany_description.setup("exact");
            });
        HTML;
        return $this->secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false);
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getAfterElementHtmlCss() {
        $html = <<<HTML
        <style>
            .admin__field-control.control .control-value {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>
        HTML;
        return $html;
    }


    public function getHtmlId()
    {
        return self::TEXT_AREA_ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work in Magento 2.4.2

```
   <?php
    
    /**
     * @author Vince Verhoeven
     */
    
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer;
    
    class Editor extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
    {
    
        const TEXT_AREA_ID = 'contentWidget';
    
        protected $_elementFactory;
    
        /**
         * @var SecureHtmlRenderer
         */
        protected $secureRenderer;
    
        /**
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            array $data = [],
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory,
            ?SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer = null
        )
        {
            $this->secureRenderer = $secureRenderer ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SecureHtmlRenderer::class);
            $this->_elementFactory = $elementFactory;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }
    
        /**
         * Prepare chooser element HTML
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element Form Element
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
         */
        public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
        {
            $input = $this->_elementFactory->create("textarea", ['data' => $element->getData()]);
            $input->setId(self::TEXT_AREA_ID);
            $input->setForm($element->getForm());
            $input->setClass("widget-option input-textarea admin__control-text");
            if ($element->getRequired()) {
                $input->addClass('required-entry');
            }
    
            $element->setData('after_element_html', $input->getElementHtml() . $this->addAfterHtmlJs() . $this->getAfterElementHtmlCss());
            return $element;
        }
    
        public function addAfterHtmlJs()
        {
            $scriptString = <<<HTML
                require([
                    'jquery',
                    'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
                ], function(jQuery){
                    wysiwygcompany_description = new wysiwygSetup('{$this->getHtmlId()}', {
                            "width":"100%%",  // defined width of editor
                            "height":"200px", // height of editor
                            "plugins":[], // for image
                            "tinymce4":{"toolbar":"formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap","plugins":"advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table",
                         }
                     });
                     wysiwygcompany_description.setup("exact");
                });
            HTML;
            return $this->secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false);
        }
    
    
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        protected function getAfterElementHtmlCss() {
            $html = <<<HTML
            <style>
                .admin__field-control.control .control-value {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            </style>
            HTML;
            return $html;
        }
    
    
        public function getHtmlId()
        {
            return self::TEXT_AREA_ID;
        }
    }
```

For Multiple editors in one widget then change $this->getHtmlId() to $element->getId()

Happy Coding